# What to do if ODIN fails to flash and device can boot only in Download mode?

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-s-4, odin

The other day I was trying to flash a new rom (Android version 5.0.1) on my Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I9505) using Odin. The old one was 5.0.1 as well but I had some problems with it.

I flashed this device once before, so I kind of knew what I had to do.
When I started flashing it gave me a message with "failed", so I tried it again. It was then showing that there was no PIT partition file anymore.
I tried flashing it with a PIT file but nothing seems to have helped it.

I can only go in download mode, not in the recovery mode. The device is stuck at:

> Firmware upgrade encountered an issue. Please select recovery mode in kies & try again

I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Unfortunately, this can be a problem you might not be able to recover from.
Try getting a PIT from this XDA forum link and see if you can flash your stock firmware after that...Good luck!
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2105328

Comment: I'd try TWRP using Odin and then Lineage. https://download.lineageos.org/jfltexx